# Make relation between a pair of SOAP request & response in SOAP extension

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, soap-client

Quite a large title :)

So I have implemented a SOAP request/response tracing in a client of mine of some service. Got huge help from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34381/Efficient-Tracing-Using-SOAP-Extensions-in-NET) article on Code Project.

Question that I have is: **How can I implement something in trace class so that I'll be able to make relation between a pair of request and response, means I would like to have some unique identifier using which I'll know while logging a response that this particular response is against that particular request.**

Comment: What technology stack are we taking about? In WCF you have custom behaviours that can pass a correlation object.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, i'm consuming asmx service and the tracer is written by implementing System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapExtension class.